# "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application"

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, desktop-application, runtime.exec

I make a Desktop application Form using C# and .NET. Then I simply deploy it and make a .EXE file of it. But when I runt his .EXE file on my other Laptop, it is going to ask me "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application".

Comment: So, what is the question? Did you install .NET Desktop Runtime?

Comment: Have you tried making a self-contained application?

Comment: I just need that when I install this application on another laptop/PC, it didn't ask me to download .NET to run this application.

Comment: @tkausl if you read the question carefully, you get the answer, I am simply asking, I just need that when I install this application on another laptop/PC, it didn't ask me to download .NET to run this application.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you wanted to use the app on another device without installing the .NET Desktop Runtime, you could've just created a self-contained app by opening the project folder that has the .csproj file in cmd or powershell and you could've ran:

1. this command to publish it in the "Debug" folder

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -c Debug
```

2. or this one for the "Release" folder

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -c Release
```

The **-r** flag is used to set the runtime id, for which you can see the catalog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).
The **-c** flag is used to set the configuration: **Release** or **Debug**.

To learn more about the **dotnet publish** command, you can read [this article on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)

Or you could've installed the.NET Desktop Runtime on your other laptop like [Augusto said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73094221/19385798)

Comment: While this is true for .NET Core/5/6, it is NOT true for .NET Framework and unfortunately, the OP hasn't clarified what they are using.

Comment: @mike thanks. I always forget about -r, but there are also --os now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'need to install .Net Desktop Runtime ‍♂️

You can download it from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0), just look for the "Desktop runtime" section. This link is for version 6.0, so maybe I'll need to look for a different version.